# Hover color on container to override inner component color

Tags: html, css

I have the below setup:

```css
.container {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.container:hover {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.item1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.item1:hover {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div>
    item 2
  </div>
  <div>
    item 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside the container, I want `item1` to have a different color, but when I hover over the container, I want to have all items the same color. With the current setup, `.item1` color is overriding the container hover color. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More specific rules are stronger. In this case a rule on a class on a an item, is stronger than inherited value.

You can create a specific rule for `.item1` - `.container:hover, .container:hover .item1 {`.

```css
.container {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.container:hover,
.container:hover .item1 {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.item1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div>
    item 2
  </div>
  <div>
    item 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to add a rule for all items on container hover - `.container:hover, .container:hover .item {`. This will require you to add the `.item` class to all items, but would be more extendable - you wouldn't have to create a separate rule for future `.item2`, `.item3` that would have different colors.

```css
.container {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.container:hover, .container:hover .item {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.item1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this style to main css.

```
.container:hover .item1 {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

If you set the item1 color on `container:hover` condition, it will overwrite the original `item1` color style.

```css
.container {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.container:hover {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.container:hover .item1 {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.item1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div>
    item 2
  </div>
  <div>
    item 3
  </div>
</div>
```